# Ignite Query Heap Full

Tags: ignite

Enviornment : Ignite-2.8.1, Java 8

I am getting heap full for my application after few hours of start. On analyzing heap dump, I see instances class org.apache.internal.processors.query.*. Looks like after query execution, it is not getting cleaned up from the heap and after some time leading to failure due to heap full.

One thing I have realized is all these entries are for queries that are triggered via ignite executor services or normal task scheduling services.

Please suggest. Attaching snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ignite is just trying to execute the SQL queries that are being sent to it. You would need to investigate the client.

On the Ignite side, you can make sure you're [using the right garbage collector and setting the heap size appropriately](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning). There's no One Good Answer, but in general, use the G1 GC and I'd start with 4Gb of heap space if you're using a lot of SQL.